# Hide the search button if at least one field is invalid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My task is to hide the search button if there is at least one field that has a type other than: Number
This is what I did in Computed:

```
filterValid () {
return (
(this.tkType !== null) && (typeof this.tkType.value === 'number') ||
(this.archiveTk !== null) && (typeof this.archiveTk.value === 'number') ||
(this.fundTk !== null) && (typeof this.fundTk.value === 'number') ||
(this.tkStatusSend !== null) && (typeof this.tkStatusSend.value === 'number') ||
(this.tkTypeMessage !== null) && (typeof this.tkTypeMessage.value === 'number')
)
}
```

```
<v-btn
  :disabled="!filterValid"
>
Поиск
</v-btn>
```

This works, but only for one select, if I make the second one invalid, the button does not disappear.
Is it possible to do my validation using only boolean operators?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `return` statement in the computed function `filterValid` and if you wish the condition `at least one field that has a type other than: Number` works then you need `&&` instead of `||`:

```js
filterValid () {
  return (this.tkType !== null) && (typeof this.tkType.value === 'number') &&
    (this.archiveTk !== null) && (typeof this.archiveTk.value === 'number') &&
    (this.fundTk !== null) && (typeof this.fundTk.value === 'number') &&
    (this.tkStatusSend !== null) && (typeof this.tkStatusSend.value === 'number') &&
    (this.tkTypeMessage !== null) && (typeof this.tkTypeMessage.value === 'number')
}
```

And finally you mentioned `hide the search button` but you linked `filterValid` to `disabled` instead of `v-show`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case, I have to select all the selections for the condition to work, and the button becomes inactive. Regarding: disabled, I put it wrong.